# Background images applied to CSS class do not appear in IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

The background images referenced by CSS do not appear in IE 7; IE 8, FireFox and Chrome work.  Changed the image format from GIF and JPG, but that didn't resolve the issue.

CSS:

```
.question{
   background-image: url("/app/scr/bsf-osb/ins/images/icons/infos-question-circle2DG.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   padding-right: 16px; 
   text-decoration: none;
   background-position: left center;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<span id="biaEstateNumberHelp" class="question" title="" alt=""></span>
```

Comment: Have you tried to give width and height? You should remove `title` and `alt` from your `span` tag as well.

Comment: Added height and width of the images to the CSS, no luck, removed title and alt as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first / in the relative path to the image:

`background-image: url("app/scr/bsf-osb/ins/images/icons/infos-question-circle2DG.png");`

You could also try applying `display: inline-block` to the element (although for IE7 this won't do anything - you need to add `*display: inline; zoom: 1;` to simulate inline-block).

Answer (score 1):

If i remember right IE takes out empty tags. Put something like `&nbsp;` inside your span

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `overflow: hidden;` ?